# Finding chains in a deeply nested hash

Tags: ruby

Given the following class with the method #find_chains the problem is to find all chains that lead to a given key_to_find.

```
class HashDeepUtils
  def initialize(hash)
    @hash = hash
    @chains = [[]]
  end

  def find_chains(key_to_find)
    if hash.has_key?(key_to_find)
      @chains[0] << key_to_find
      @chains.unshift([])
    else
      @hash.each_key do |key|
        deep_utils = HashDeepUtils.new(@hash[key])
        probable_chains = deep_utils.find_chains(key_to_find)
        if probable_chains.any?
          @chains[0] << key
          @chains[0] += probable_chains[0]
        end
      end
    end

    return @chains
  end
end
```

The following tests were written by me to test that behaviour.

```
class TestChainFinding < Minitest::Test
  def test_finds_single_chain
    hash = {test: 'test'}
    deep_utils = HashDeepUtils.new(hash)
    assert_equal [[:test]], deep_utils.find_chains(:test)
  end

  def test_finds_nested_chain
    hash = {test: {foo: 'bar'}}
    deep_utils = HashDeepUtils.new(hash)
    assert_equal [[:test, :foo]], deep_utils.find_chains(:foo)
  end

  def test_finds_multiple_nested_chains
    hash = {test: {foo: 'bar'}, foo: 'baz'}
    deep_utils = HashDeepUtils.new(hash)
    assert_equal [[:test, :foo], [:foo]], deep_utils.find_chains(:foo)
  end
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why the third test is failing.

Comment: Third test is failing because `if hash.has_key?(key_to_find)` won’t execute the `else` clause for nested `{test: {foo: .. }}` since `foo` key is found on the top level.

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: Yes, understood. I was unaware and didn't try again, after it was reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recursive method**

```
def chains(hash, key)
  hash.each_with_object([]) do |(k,v), arr|
    arr.concat([[k]]) if k == key
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      a = chains(hash[k], key)
      arr.concat(a.map { |b| [k, *b] }) unless a.empty?
    end
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
chains({ test: {foo: 'bar'}, foo: 'baz' }, :foo)
  #=> [[:test, :foo], [:foo]]

chains({ test: { foo: { baz: 'baz', foo: 'foo' } }, foo: 'foo' }, :foo)
  #=> [[:test, :foo], [:test, :foo, :foo], [:foo]]
```

**Explanation**

I've inserted some `puts` statements to show the steps and calculations performed by the recursive method.

```
def chains(hash, key, lvl=0)
  level_indent = ' '*(4*lvl)
  loop_indent  = ' '*(4*lvl + 2)
  puts "\n#{level_indent}lvl=#{lvl}"
  puts "#{level_indent}entered chains(#{hash}, #{key})"
  puts "#{level_indent}hash=#{hash}"
  hash.each_with_object([]) do |(k,v), arr|
    puts "#{loop_indent}k=#{k}, v=#{v}, arr=#{arr}"
    puts "#{loop_indent}#{k}==#{key} is #{k==key}"   
    arr.concat([[k]]) if k == key
    puts "#{loop_indent}arr=#{arr}" if k == key
    puts "#{loop_indent}#{v}.is_a?(Hash) = #{v.is_a?(Hash)}"
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      puts "#{loop_indent}calling chains(#{hash[k]}, #{key}, #{lvl+1})"
      a = chains(hash[k], key, lvl+1)
      puts "#{loop_indent}a=#{a} returned from lvl #{lvl+1}"
      puts "#{loop_indent}a.map { |b| [k, *b] }= #{a.map { |b| [k, *b] }}"
      arr.concat(a.map { |b| [k, *b] }) unless a.empty?
      puts "#{loop_indent}arr=#{arr}"
    end
  end
end
```

```
chains({ test: {foo: 'bar'}, foo: 'baz' }, :foo)
  # lvl=0
  # entered chains({:test=>{:foo=>"bar"}, :foo=>"baz"}, foo)
  # hash={:test=>{:foo=>"bar"}, :foo=>"baz"}
  #   k=test, v={:foo=>"bar"}, arr=[]
  #   test==foo is false
  #   {:foo=>"bar"}.is_a?(Hash) = true
  #   calling chains({:foo=>"bar"}, foo, 1)
```

```
  #     lvl=1
  #     entered chains({:foo=>"bar"}, foo)
  #     hash={:foo=>"bar"}
  #       k=foo, v=bar, arr=[]
  #       foo==foo is true
  #       arr=[[:foo]]
  #       bar.is_a?(Hash) = false
```

```
  #   a=[[:foo]] returned from lvl 1
  #   a.map { |b| [k, *b] }= [[:test, :foo]]
  #   arr=[[:test, :foo]]
  #   k=foo, v=baz, arr=[[:test, :foo]]
  #   foo==foo is true
  #   arr=[[:test, :foo], [:foo]]
  #   baz.is_a?(Hash) = false
  #=> [[:test, :foo], [:foo]]
```

```
chains({ test: { foo: { baz: 'baz', foo: 'foo' } }, foo: 'foo' }, :foo)
  # lvl=0
  # entered chains({:test=>{:foo=>{:baz=>"baz", :foo=>"foo"}}, :foo=>"foo"}, foo)
  # hash={:test=>{:foo=>{:baz=>"baz", :foo=>"foo"}}, :foo=>"foo"}
  #   k=test, v={:foo=>{:baz=>"baz", :foo=>"foo"}}, arr=[]
  #   test==foo is false
  #   {:foo=>{:baz=>"baz", :foo=>"foo"}}.is_a?(Hash) = true
  #   calling chains({:foo=>{:baz=>"baz", :foo=>"foo"}}, foo, 1)
```

```
  #     lvl=1
  #     entered chains({:foo=>{:baz=>"baz", :foo=>"foo"}}, foo)
  #     hash={:foo=>{:baz=>"baz", :foo=>"foo"}}
  #       k=foo, v={:baz=>"baz", :foo=>"foo"}, arr=[]
  #       foo==foo is true
  #       arr=[[:foo]]
  #       {:baz=>"baz", :foo=>"foo"}.is_a?(Hash) = true
  #       calling chains({:baz=>"baz", :foo=>"foo"}, foo, 2)
```

```
  #         lvl=2
  #         entered chains({:baz=>"baz", :foo=>"foo"}, foo)
  #         hash={:baz=>"baz", :foo=>"foo"}
  #           k=baz, v=baz, arr=[]
  #           baz==foo is false
  #           baz.is_a?(Hash) = false
  #           k=foo, v=foo, arr=[]
  #           foo==foo is true
  #           arr=[[:foo]]
  #           foo.is_a?(Hash) = false
```

```
  #       a=[[:foo]] returned from lvl 2
  #       a.map { |b| [k, *b] }= [[:foo, :foo]]
  #       arr=[[:foo], [:foo, :foo]]
```

```
  #   a=[[:foo], [:foo, :foo]] returned from lvl 1
  #   a.map { |b| [k, *b] }= [[:test, :foo], [:test, :foo, :foo]]
  #   arr=[[:test, :foo], [:test, :foo, :foo]]
  #   k=foo, v=foo, arr=[[:test, :foo], [:test, :foo, :foo]]
  #   foo==foo is true
  #   arr=[[:test, :foo], [:test, :foo, :foo], [:foo]]
  #   foo.is_a?(Hash) = false
  #=> [[:test, :foo], [:test, :foo, :foo], [:foo]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You are abusing OOP by creating classes where they are absolutely unnecessary. The pure recursive function perfectly solves the task:

```
def chains(hash, key, path = [], memo = [])
  hash.each_with_object(memo) do |(k, v), acc|
    memo.push(path + [k]) if k == key
    chains(v, key, (path + [k]), memo) if v.is_a?(Hash)
  end
end

hash = {test: {foo: 'bar'}, foo: 'baz'}
chains(hash, :foo)
#⇒ [[:test, :foo], [:foo]]

chains({test: {foo: {baz: 'baz', foo: 'foo'}}, foo: 'foo'}, :foo)
#⇒ [[:test, :foo], [:test, :foo, :foo], [:foo]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer without abusing OOP, but closer to the original code in the question.

```
class HashDeepUtils
  def initialize(hash)
    @hash = hash
  end

  def find_chains(key_to_find, hash = @hash)
    chains = []

    if hash.has_key?(key_to_find)
      chains.unshift([key_to_find])
    end

    hash.each_key do |key|
      next unless hash[key].is_a?(Hash)

      further_chains = find_chains(key_to_find, hash[key])
      further_chains.each do |further_chain|
        chains.unshift([])
        chains[0] << key
        chains[0] += further_chain
      end
    end

    chains
  end
end
```